# Gnuplot: xtic showing every given number of data elements

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot, bar-chart

Let me just say that i am new to gnuplot...
Trying to plot from file :

```
"Dataset " "Min_sup (%)" Itemsets "Rules " "Exec_time (s)"  
Giorno_1 0.1 16392 260337 15.23  
Giorno_1 0.2 9719 155963 11.96  
Giorno_1 5.0 275 2495 6.43  
Giorno_2 0.1 15023 212058 14.14  
Giorno_2 0.2 8503 115766 14.62  
Giorno_2 0.4 2962 43710 12.90  
Giorno_2 0.8 1603 17514 10.53  
Giorno_2 1.0 1223 14701 9.96
```

I want to plot using as x axis the the "Min_sup" column AND the "Dataset" column. Here's the problem: as you see the "Dataset" column has value that repeat and i want to show them only one time in the graph.

So basically i am searching for a way to select when to plot the the x2tics.

[image: Link to the graph]

The gnuplot script i am using is:

```
set style data histograms  
set grid  
set terminal png nocrop enhanced font verdana 12 size 1024,768  
set output "graph.png"  
set xtics norangelimit   
set xtics border in scale 1,0.5 nomirror rotate by -45  offset character 0, 0  
set x2tics ("dataset1" "Giorno_1","dataset2" 2,"dataset3" 3,"dataset4" 4,"dataset5" 5,"dataset6" 6)  
set x2tics scale 10  
set xlabel "Minimum support in %"  
set ylabel "# of "  
set style fill transparent solid 0.6 noborder  
set datafile separator " "  
plot 'prova.dat' using 4:xtic(2):x2ticlabels(1) title col , \  
'prova.dat' using 3:xtic(2):x2ticlabels(1) title col
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit tricky to do that. Basically, you must save the "Dataset" value of the current and the previous row and compare them. If they are equal, don't set a new x2ticlabel, other use it as new label.

The values are stored with the `using` command:

```
s1 = ''
s2 = ''
plot 'prova.dat' using (s2 = s1, s1 = stringcolumn(1), $4):...
```

Here, `s2` is assigned the value of `s1` and, therefore, hold the value of the previous row. Then, `s1` is assigned the string-value of the first column. With `$4`, the fourth column is used. This has nothing to do with the comparision, but is the 'normal' part of the using statement (`using 4` and `using ($4)` is almost the same).

The check is done in the `x2ticlabel` function:

```
x2tic(s1 eq s2 ? 1/0 : s1)
```

This uses the value of the variable `s1` as x2ticlabel if `s1` and `s2` are equal. Otherwise it uses `1/0`. With this you'll get some warnings of the kind `Tic label does not evaluate as string!`, but that is what you want.

Finally, I removed some default settings from your script:

```
set terminal png nocrop enhanced font verdana 12 size 1024,768
set output "graph.png"

set style data histograms
set grid
set xtics nomirror rotate by -45
set x2tics left scale 10
set xlabel "Minimum support in %"
set ylabel "# of "
set style fill transparent solid 0.6 noborder

s1=''; s2='';
plot 'prova.dat' using (s2 = s1, s1 = stringcolumn(1), $4):xtic(2):x2tic(s1 eq s2 ? 1/0 : s1)  title col , \
'prova.dat' using 3 title col
```

Gives (with 4.6.3):

[image]